# How do I read the console output of a Windows GUI application?

Tags: windows, console

If I remember correctly, Windows applications can be compiled as console or GUI applications. One of the main differences is that console applications get a console automatically, while GUI applications do not (although they could get one if they wanted by calling [`AllocConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Common wisdom says if you use `printf` or `std::cout` from a GUI application, that output simply goes nowhere, because there's no console to print it to. But I know it's possible to read it, because when I run some applications from a terminal on Linux using Wine, I can read the output of `printf` and similar functions. (Yes, I'm sure it's the application printing that, not Wine.)

How could I do that on Windows? I've tried [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) and even though it shows a bit of debug text coming from the application, it doesn't show as much as Wine does, probably because DebugView is restricted to calls to `OutputDebugString`.

Comment: No; What you describe must be programmed by the author of the application.

Comment: To my instinct I think you can try to run the program from command prompt and redirect the output to a file, like `gui_application.exe > output.txt`. Not sure if it works, and I am curious whether it works.

Comment: @KennethL yes, it works. Interesting. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You write "If I remember correctly, Windows applications can be compiled as console or GUI applications" <-- Do you have a source for this claim? Certainly visual studio offers  different templates.. But that doesn't mean different compilers!!

Comment: I did not mean to say different compilers were used. Whether an application is a CLI or GUI application is marked, as far as I know, as a flag in the executable header.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Invoke it as `gui_application.exe > output.txt` to have stdout go into the file

Invoke it as `gui_application.exe > output.txt 2>&1` to have stdout and stderr go into the file

If you are using the windows `start` command, you need to remember that `start` is an application itself, therefore `start /wait gui_application.exe > output.txt` will not do what you want because it is redirecting the stdout for `start`.

However you can escape the pertinent values:

Invoke it as `start /wait gui_application.exe ^> output.txt` to have stdout go into the file

Invoke it as `start /wait gui_application.exe ^> output.txt 2^>^&1` to have stdout and stderr go into the file